# Can I reference on a variable within a python dictionary? How do I programm a gridsearch for hyperparameters depending on each other?

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I want to optimize Hyperparmeters for my customised sklearn model using `randomizedsearchCV`.

Unfortunately there are two parameters depending on each other.

Meaning:  the size of `n_unit` is dependent on `k`.

Example: when `k` is 2, then `n_units` should be a list of size 2.
When `k` is 3 then `n_units` has to be of size 3.

So I basically need something like:

```
dict(K=scipy.stats.randint(1,50),
n_units=[np.random.randint(1,60,K)])
```

However, this does not work. Is there any way to search for hyperparameters depending on each other?

Comment: Can you assign your dictionary to a variable? If you can and the name of the key (K) is not going to change then you can n_units=[np.random.randint(1,60,myDict.get(K, some_default_value))])

Comment: This is not a good idea. Either you should pass only acceptable combinations as tuples and configure the estimator to use them or You should just pass all the available possibilities to the search and then take care in your estimator about the relationship between the two. You should raise an error if the constraint is not satisfied. RandomizedSearchCV has a param `error_score` which you can use to handle the errors raised from estimator.

Comment: Show your complete code and we can work on a solution.

Comment: Tried to reword the question to make it more clear, and improved formatting a bit.

Comment: @VivekKumar What do you mean the whole code? I now used a workaround as you said only including valid combinations (all n_units have the size of the maximal k value, so that for smaller values the rest of the unit arrays is just not used. I was thinking about the error score mechnism as well. Thanks you

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you:)

Comment: @VivekKumar I used "error_score = 0" in my RandomizedSearchCV. However, the search does not continue after an "AssertionError" occured. Is there any trick to tell it to just continue the search afterwards with a new parameter combination

Comment: Please post the code and the full stack trace of error